# The difference between ' and "

Tags: command-line, bash, 22.04

I have a command:

```bash
synclient -l | awk -v param_name=$param_name '$1==param_name {print $(NF)}'
```

and its output is just: `0`.

But if I replace both `'` with `"`, I'm getting:

```
Command 'NF' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install byobu
awk: cmd. line:1: ==param_name {print }
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ syntax error
```

The same error appears when I use `sh -c` on the commands:

```bash
sh -c "synclient -l | awk -v param_name=$param_name '$1==param_name {print $(NF)}'"
```

```bash
sh -c 'synclient -l | awk -v param_name=$param_name "$1==param_name {print $(NF)}"'
```

What's the difference between `'` and `"` here? Why does it happen?

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html

Comment: A variable `'$param'` within single quote characters is not expanded, and this happens in both cases in your original question. Use only double quote characters around variables `"$param"`.

Answer (score 2):

From [`bash` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html):

> Enclosing characters in single quotes (`'`) preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. [...]

> Enclosing characters in double quotes (`"`) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of `$`, `` ` ``, `\`, and, when history expansion is enabled, `!`.

Double quotes is clearly the wrong method here.

In your case, the `$` is is not preserved for `awk`, but evaluated by `bash`, which leads to 2 errors.

- `bash` expands `$1` which is empty in your case, that is why `awk` complains about a syntax error.
- `$(NF)` is [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html), so `bash` tries to run a command with name `NF`, which is not available.

---

Also, you should double quote `$param_name`, otherwise it will lead to an error, if it contains space.

```bash
-v param_name="$param_name"
```

Comment: I'd like to use the code as a part of a custom shortcut but adding the double quote stops it from working completely. [more](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1465502/how-to-use-a-bash-command-as-a-custom-shortcut)